# Paste without excel format only text

Tags: excel

The problem is the following:

1. Copy text from excel including from multiple cells.
2. Paste it into a software text box.

The problem is point 2, since when I paste it I get the squares.

If there is no way then a program that allows me to do that.

Comment: What program, with what code?

Answer (score 0):

Use an unformatted text editing tool as a jumping off point, such as notepad in windows.